# JSONata get parent element

Tags: javascript, traversal, jsonata

In a rather complex JSON-object I am trying to get a key with a parent value.

```
{
    "provinces": [
        {
            "short": "ska",
            "tiletype": "water",
            "provinceOutlinePath": "M255.848,145.321l19.839,0.054l12.677,8.62l6.085,-8.62l-8.62,-29.41l-30.488,13.637l0.507,15.719Z",
            "unionParts": [
                {
                    "id": "main",
                    "unionPartPath": "M255.848,145.321l19.839,0.054l12.677,8.62l6.085,-8.62l-8.62,-29.41l-30.488,13.637l0.507,15.719Z"
                },
 {
                    "id": "main",
                    "unionPartPath": "M255.848,145.321l19.839,0.054l12.677,8.62l6.085,-8.62l-8.62,-29.41l-30.488,13.637l0.507,15.719Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "short": "nws",
            "tiletype": "water",
            "provinceOutlinePath": "M140.038,0.667l34.86,68.197l-6.338,27.888l12.677,3.169l70.988,-17.747l100.144,-62.115l1.268,-19.392l-213.599,0Z",
            "unionParts": [
                {
                    "id": "main",
                    "unionPartPath": "M140.038,0.667l34.86,68.197l-6.338,27.888l12.677,3.169l70.988,-17.747l100.144,-62.115l1.268,-19.392l-213.599,0Z"
                }
            ]
        }
   ]
}
```

I want to alter the object to:

```
[
  { 
    "short": ska,
    "unionPartPath": "<Path>"
  },
  { 
    "short": ska,
    "unionPartPath": "<AnotherPath>"
  },
  { 
    "short": nws,
    "unionPartPath": "<Path>"
  }
]
```

I already browsed the whole docs and found nothing like a `.parent()` method.
Maybe the desired result could be achieved with some higher order functions but currently I have no clue how to implement this.

Comment: You don't need to *get a key with a parent value*, you just need to loop through all the items in the `provinces` array, and then loop through all the items in the `unionParts` array while keeping a reference to the value of `short` of the item at the current iteration of the top loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this in JSONata, you need the following expression

```
provinces.($short := short; unionParts.{
  'short': $short,
  'unionPartPath': unionPartPath
})
```

See http://try.jsonata.org/H1goy6AjE

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

> Here I have used **map()** method defined on Arrays. You please make sure to use proper path.
>
> I have just specified `<yourPath>` as you have mentioned `<Path>`, `<AnotherPath>` (You know well that what does it means so just replace)

Assign the object to any variable e.g. to **obj**. And now we can use this 1 line statement to get the result

`result = obj.provinces.map((obj2) => obj2.unionParts.map((obj3) => {return {"short": obj2.short, "unionPartPath": "<yourPath>"}}))`

Initialization »

```
> let obj = {
...     "provinces": [
...         {
.....             "short": "ska",
.....             "tiletype": "water",
.....             "provinceOutlinePath": "M255.848,145.321l19.839,0.054l12.677,8.62l6.085,-8.62l-8.62,-29.41l-30.488,13.637l0.507,15.719Z",
.....             "unionParts": [
.....                 {
.......                     "id": "main",
.......                     "unionPartPath": "M255.848,145.321l19.839,0.054l12.677,8.62l6.085,-8.62l-8.62,-29.41l-30.488,13.637l0.507,15.719Z"
.......                 },
.....                 {
.......                     "id": "main",
.......                     "unionPartPath": "M255.848,145.321l19.839,0.054l12.677,8.62l6.085,-8.62l-8.62,-29.41l-30.488,13.637l0.507,15.719Z"
.......                 }
.....             ]
.....         },
...         {
.....             "short": "nws",
.....             "tiletype": "water",
.....             "provinceOutlinePath": "M140.038,0.667l34.86,68.197l-6.338,27.888l12.677,3.169l70.988,-17.747l100.144,-62.115l1.268,-19.392l-213.599,0Z",
.....             "unionParts": [
.....                 {
.......                     "id": "main",
.......                     "unionPartPath": "M140.038,0.667l34.86,68.197l-6.338,27.888l12.677,3.169l70.988,-17.747l100.144,-62.115l1.268,-19.392l-213.599,0Z"
.......                 }
.....             ]
.....         }
...    ]
... }
undefined
>
```

Finally »

```
> result = obj.provinces.map((obj2) => obj2.unionParts.map((obj3) => {return {"short": obj2.short, "unionPartPath": "<yourPath>"}}))
[ [ { short: 'ska', unionPartPath: '<yourPath>' },
    { short: 'ska', unionPartPath: '<yourPath>' } ],
  [ { short: 'nws', unionPartPath: '<yourPath>' } ] ]
>
```

Pretty printing the object »

```
> console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4)) // Pretty print of object
[
    [
        {
            "short": "ska",
            "unionPartPath": "<yourPath>"
        },
        {
            "short": "ska",
            "unionPartPath": "<yourPath>"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "short": "nws",
            "unionPartPath": "<yourPath>"
        }
    ]
]
undefined
>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `for-of` loop should do it:

```js
const jsonData = {
  "provinces": [{
      "short": "ska",
      "tiletype": "water",
      "provinceOutlinePath": "M255.848,145.321l19.839,0.054l12.677,8.62l6.085,-8.62l-8.62,-29.41l-30.488,13.637l0.507,15.719Z",
      "unionParts": [{
          "id": "main",
          "unionPartPath": "M255.848,145.321l19.839,0.054l12.677,8.62l6.085,-8.62l-8.62,-29.41l-30.488,13.637l0.507,15.719Z"
        },
        {
          "id": "main",
          "unionPartPath": "M255.848,145.321l19.839,0.054l12.677,8.62l6.085,-8.62l-8.62,-29.41l-30.488,13.637l0.507,15.719Z"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "short": "nws",
      "tiletype": "water",
      "provinceOutlinePath": "M140.038,0.667l34.86,68.197l-6.338,27.888l12.677,3.169l70.988,-17.747l100.144,-62.115l1.268,-19.392l-213.599,0Z",
      "unionParts": [{
        "id": "main",
        "unionPartPath": "M140.038,0.667l34.86,68.197l-6.338,27.888l12.677,3.169l70.988,-17.747l100.144,-62.115l1.268,-19.392l-213.599,0Z"
      }]
    }
  ]
};

const result = [];
for (let p of jsonData.provinces) {
  for (let part of p.unionParts) {
    result.push({short: p.short, unionPartPath: part.unionPartPath});
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution that use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) in conjunction with [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter) features:

```js
const jsonData = {"provinces":[{"short":"ska","tiletype":"water","provinceOutlinePath":"M255.848,145.321l19.839,0.054l12.677,8.62l6.085,-8.62l-8.62,-29.41l-30.488,13.637l0.507,15.719Z","unionParts":[{"id":"main","unionPartPath":"M255.848,145.321l19.839,0.054l12.677,8.62l6.085,-8.62l-8.62,-29.41l-30.488,13.637l0.507,15.719Z"},{"id":"main","unionPartPath":"M255.848,145.321l19.839,0.054l12.677,8.62l6.085,-8.62l-8.62,-29.41l-30.488,13.637l0.507,15.719Z"}]},{"short":"nws","tiletype":"water","provinceOutlinePath":"M140.038,0.667l34.86,68.197l-6.338,27.888l12.677,3.169l70.988,-17.747l100.144,-62.115l1.268,-19.392l-213.599,0Z","unionParts":[{"id":"main","unionPartPath":"M140.038,0.667l34.86,68.197l-6.338,27.888l12.677,3.169l70.988,-17.747l100.144,-62.115l1.268,-19.392l-213.599,0Z"}]}]};


let res = jsonData.provinces.reduce((acc, {short, unionParts}) =>
{
    unionParts.forEach(({unionPartPath}) => acc.push({short, unionPartPath}));
    return acc;
}, []);


console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```